# Which theoretical models are there between quantum mechanics and cosmology?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, cosmology, astrophysics, continuum-mechanics

I'm an enthusiast/hobbyist right now and I'm quite curious about the subject of understanding which scales come between the quantum scale (ab initio/first principles) and the macroscopic scale. After the macroscopic scale which scales best describe the multiple scales onward until the astrophysical/cosmological scales? Which theoretical models are used for each scale? Is there a way to convert particle physics data (quantum mechanics/ab initio) to contiuum mechanics?

EDIT:
This is more of the structure I was after:
[image]

Comment: This question is well-intended, and may be useful, but I'm really concerned that there are more than one correct answers to this, and any discussion about them will quickly degenerate into a semantics disaster amongst our commenters, hence the close vote, which I made with a bit of hesitation.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer  you are right Jerry, thinking about it, the question is actually covered in the intro chapters to most decent Pop Sci books on string theory or particle physics in much more depth.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer I do think that I should have made the question clearer and I have added a graphical representation of what I am trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, and actually popular science books about string theory, particle physics or cosmology are pretty much obliged to write about the subject in much greater depth than here.

Anyway here's  my short attempt starting with the quantum scale and using QM rather than QFT.

We have plenty of equations, all of which incorporate the [Planck constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant),  that describe how electrons move around and many of these basic equations include a variable (usually called n) that describes systems in a quantum way when n is given a low value and then gives a classical description when n is given a high value.  This is Bohr's [Correspondence Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) in practical terms, as far as I know.

> Is there a way to convert particle physics data (quantum mechanics/ab initio) to contiuum mechanics?

The above is a very basic description for one particular case of moving from the quantum to the classical world, hopefully you will get more sophisticated  answers from people who know more than I do.

So then we move on to Newtons Laws of motion and Maxwell's equations for  classical world mechanics and electromagnetism respectively and these work for describing almost everything around us, and did so up to 1900.

Once we got to trying to explain measurement discrepancies for Mercury's orbit, (or the problem of understanding  how electric and magnetic waves propagate in empty space), Einstein could explain them only by blending space and time into 4D spacetime, discarding the aether hypothesis and that's  what eventually led to [General Relativity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity), which is what we use for cosmological scales.